# jQuery DatePicker plugin format date and ASP.NET MVC Get request

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have an asp.net mvc project with jQuery DatePicker controls. My page looks like this:

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm())
   { %>
   <%= Html.ValidationSummary(true) %>
....
      <%= Html.TextBox("DateReport", Model.DateReport.ToShortDateString(), new { @class = "dateField" })%>                
      <input type="submit" value="Load report" /> 
<% } %>
<Code for my grid here>
<div class="pager">
    <%= Html.PageLinks(Model.PagingInfo, x => Url.Action("List", "History", new { page = x, dateReport = Model.DateReport }))%>
</div>
```

Controller method:

```
public ActionResult List([DefaultValue(1)] int page, DateTime? dateReport)
{
    ...
    return View(model);
}
```

When I first load the page, the datepicker's text box shows the correct date format: **30.01.2011**.

When I change the date and submit "Load report" - the correct date is sent to the Controller and it returns the correct data for the report. The date in the datepicker textbox is also in the correct format: **30.01.2011**.

But then I click on the link for the next page in the grid, I get returned a datepicker textbox date in an incorrect format, like this: **01/30/2011 00:00:00**.

Please, help me - what I doing wrong!?

Comment: What URL does your next link go to?

Comment: e.g. 2 page: http://localhost:32538/History/List/2?dateReport=02%2F15%2F2010%2000%3A00%3A00

Comment: "But then I click on the link for the next page in the grid" - what does this mean exactly? You've described the controller action / model that *is working correctly* but haven't provided the code that isn't - as far as I can tell.